Migrated documents are not the same size
I recently performed a migration between sites. It was a bit of a manual process in terms of developing using the client object model in C#. Essentially, for each file, I retrieved the memory stream then uploaded a new document to where it needed to be. The issue is some of the large files may have errored in process resulting in a corrupt file.
To try and detect corrupt files I created a file size verification step. The issue with that is seemingly 90% of non-corrupted files changed size between in the process. Most of these files are Microsoft Office documents. (ie. .doc, .docx, .xlsx, .msg, etc...) PDF's, text files, zips, and others match in size.
I'm assuming the files changed size because on uploading they updated to a newer Office file. What I would like to know is can this file size be quantified somehow or is there another way I can verify a large qty (~17k files, 38 GB) of files for corruption.

SharePoint will not automatically update files to the latest version (i.e. there is no automatic conversion from .doc to docx).
SharePoint has a mechanism called property promotion. This injects additional metadata (and schema information) into certain file types such as docx, xlsx, pptx, vsdx, msg and tiff.
For example, a typical msg file will increase by 7-10 kB after uploading to SharePoint.
tiff files are a special case. The compression used by SharePoint may not be as efficient as the initial compression method used and as a result the final tiff files with metadata may increase in size in a serious way (2x, 3x, ...).
There are also file types that are not affected (e.g., pdf, zip, jpg, ...).
You may therefore expect that some files will increase in size.

That's great information! Sounds like I won't be able to quantify a set change factor for these files, then. To the other point then, is there any way of detecting corrupted files using SharePoint CSOM? Seemingly the primary issue is some larger files like mp4's may have been interrupted during the large file upload process. Otherwise, I will have to devise a method for each file extension (ie. using ffmpeg).
